# firefox still showing up in bleachbit after removal

Tags: firefox, bleachbit

I thought I had removed firefox from my system (prefer chromium) using

```
sudo apt-get remove firefox
```

however, when I open bleachbit there is still a category that allows me to clean cache/backup/cookies and whatever for firefox. But I thought I had already deleted firefox?

So did I not completely remove firefox?

Comment: I am not sure and can not verify at the moment, but I believe that Bleachbit always shows all its options it has, whether they apply to your installation or not. Also removing a package from your system does not remove your user data related to that package, so your Firefox profile in your home directory is likely still intact.

Comment: I think that you will have to use '--purge' option on remove to delete all configuration- and cache files for an application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes: as you suspected, BleachBit shows the Firefox section only if the Firefox configuration files exist on your system, so you can run this command to delete the Firefox user profile

`rm -rf ~/.mozilla/firefox`

Then you can delete the Firefox cache using BleachBit. Recent versions of Firefox have it under another directory tree.

As Soren A pointed out, removing a package normally using APT does not remove its configuration files.